# Java streams statement: find the error

Tags: java, java-stream

This works as expected

```
Collection<String> items = combo.getItems();
items.stream().filter(item -> item.startsWith("New")).findFirst()...
```

But this fails to compile. Why?

```
Collection items = combo.getItems();
items.stream().map(Object::toString).filter(item -> item.startsWith("New")).findFirst()...
                                                         ^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Because `Collection` is a *raw* type. **Don't use *raw* types**, since the entire statement become *raw* when you do.

Comment: `map` takes a *raw* `Function` and hence its return type is `Object` and not a `String`

Comment: @YCF_L It only works because you didn't use the *raw* `Collection items`.

Comment: @YCF_L your demo is incorrect.  The second example uses `Collection items`, not `Collection<String> items`.

Comment: oops I don't notice that @Andreas

Comment: this is correct @Paul my mistake I dont notice that

Comment: The error is `unchecked call to raw type`. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.html, which says "However, a non-generic class or interface type is not a raw type."  This works: `Collection<Object> items = `

Comment: You may also use `Collection<?>` which means “Collection of unknown type” rather than `Collection`, which means “I don’t use Generics”…